# Bootstrap change color on hover using classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my snippet, if you hover over the text it turns the text red, however, rather than hardcoding `color:red` I'd prefer to use Bootstrap's native class `text-danger`. Is this possible?

```css
.text-primary:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="text-primary">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: It is possible, but not with CSS (only with Javascript)

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap's color for `text-danger` is `#dc3545` and it's in a variable ( [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) ) `--red` so you can use that.

these are the [available variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#available-variables)

```css
.text-primary:hover {
  color: var(--red) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="text-primary">Hello World!</div>
```